# GCP project quota issue with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm using Terraform to create GCP projects (google_project resource) through service account inpersonnation and I'm hitting a quota issue:

> Error: Error waiting for creating folder: Error code 8, message: The project cannot be created because you have exceeded your allotted project quota.

My problem is identical to this [Github Issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/1886)

I've requested and obtained a project quota increase and I'm able to create projects in the GCP console but not with the service account.

The proposed solution is to use another service account but this is really inconvenient.

- Is it possible to display the project quota associated with the service account ?
- Is there a way to reset or update the project quota associated with the service account so that I can avoid to setup a new one ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an increased quota for a specific service account you have to fill a request to Google Cloud Platform specifying both the desired quota and the service account where you want this change to be applied. If you don't specify a service account in the email addresses box and instead you just include your personal email this quota increase will be applied to your personal email.

Currently, I'm not aware of any way to get the number of remaining projects for a specific service account. However, I found this [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174229984) where a similar request was made. You can star it as you also want to have this feature and post a comment.

Comment: thank you, I stared the issue and added a comment on it